# Display object from knex into ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, knex.js

I am trying to display a object in my ejs file but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, I keep getting Object, object. I can get it to display in the terminal but once I try and display it on the ejs page it no longer works.

all what i'm trying to do is count the number of rows and display that number on my ejs pages.

app.js

```
// render files 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    knex.where({ID: '1'})
    .select()
    .count()
    .from("Table")
    .then((results) =>{
        res.render('Page', {Lcount: results});
    })    
});
```

I've tried to do is several ways on my ejs page but I can't seem to figure it out

ejs page

```
<%= Lcount %> //displays object, object 

<%- Lcount %> //displays object, object


 <% for (var i=0; i <Lcount.length; i++ ) { %>
            
                <%- Lcount[i] %> // displays object, object

                <% } %> 


<% for (let i=0; i <Lcount.length; i++ ) { %>
            
                <%= Lcount[i] %> //displays object object

                <% } %>
```

for anyone having a similar issue I figured out what my the problem was with my code I needed to have a alias for my count so I can call it in my ejs. Since count() is one of the cases in knex when you are not returning a row of a table you are essentially making your own row based on your query.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    knex("Table")
    .where({ ID: '1' })
    .count("ID" ,{as: 'count'}) //alias setup here 
    .first()
    .then((results) => {
            res.render('Page', {
                title: 'Home',
                Lcount: results
            });
        })   
});

//ejs

<% = Lcount.count %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your knex query return an array of object:

> [ { count: '11' } ]

As i understand you want to count the records by defined ID. So it would be more readable to write your query this way:

```
knex("Table")
 .where({ ID: '1' })
 .count()
 .first() // Similar to select, but only retrieves & resolves with the first record from the query.
 .then((results) => {
   res.render('Page', { Lcount: results });
 });
```

The result will be an object:

> { count: '2' }

Then you can if you want pass the result this way:

```
res.render('Page', { 
 Lcount: results.count 
});
```

In your views/Page.ejs file:

```
<%= Lcount %>
```

In case you forgot to set the view engine:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: Okay, I got it to display in the terminal as an object but on the ejs page im still not able to display the results it still only shows object object. Any idea what i'm doing wrong there?

Comment: <%= Lcount %> should do the trick, see my updated answer

Comment: i'm not sure why this isnt working I have my view engine setup. when I use "Lcount: results.count" the terminal says it undefined but it works fine when I dont include the ".count" and just use "Lcount: results", also i'm using "<% = Lcount %>" in my ejs page. I'm thinking the issue is because ".count" isnt working right. any idea how I can get that to work? Also i'm using ".first()" instead of ".select()".

Comment: I don't understand either, i created a simple server with your code and it works fine. Did you put you ejs file in "views" folder ?

Comment: yea all my ejs files are in my views folder, it doest make sense this should work as is.

Comment: Could you past the result of the query

Comment: when I use "Lcount: results" my query result is { '': 26 } and my ejs page shows object object. when I use "Lcount: results.count" my query result is "undefined" and my ejs page doesnt show anything. I'm trying to get the 26 to show on my ejs page.

Comment: Ok, could you post your db table schema ?

Comment: this is the basic outline of my table that  i'm trying to pull from,                                                                           
[Table] 
[Number]  INT          NOT NULL,  - P Key 
[Status]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Type]    VARCHAR (20) NULL,
[SDate]   VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[CDate]   VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[ID]      INT          NULL, - F key 
[Emp_ID]  INT          NULL, - F key

Comment: Just to be sure: the result you got is really : { '': 26 } ??

Comment: Yes, i've been playing around with it and when I do "Lcount : results" with "<% =Lcount.results%>" in the terminal I get : { '': 26 } but on the ejs page its blank. when I use  "Lcount: results" and "<% =Lcount %>" in the terminal I get : { '': 26 } but on the ejs page it says object object. but if I use "Lcount: results.count" and use "<% =Lcount.count%>" in the terminal I get undefined and blank on the ejs page. I've also tried "<% =Lcount.ID%>" but its the same as when I use ".results"

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the result could be

> { ": 26 }

It seems to be malformed. To find where it goes wrong, what you can do, is to try this simple query directly from you database and paste the result:

> SELECT count(ID) FROM Table WHERE ID = 1;

Comment: the results of that in my database is 26, I even counted it by hand it has 26 rows when the ID is '1'. so the query results in my app.js terminal is right.  why do you think it is malformed?

Comment: As i said I don't understand how the result could be like { ": 26 }, it is not complete. The SQL query is good, and i tested the knex query i provided which is good too. This should be something else. Try with another field to test.

Comment: I've tried several different columns to count by with different tables to pull the data from and they all have the same format { " " : Number }. Should there be something where the " " is?  when I take out the .first() in the knex query is looks like this [ { '': Number } ]. I guess I dont understand why you are saying it is malformed, what should the output look like?

Comment: Okay, so I realized I was using .from() to pull from the table not knex(), so I fixed that. so i'm using 'Lcount: results.count' and on my ejs page using <%= Lcount.count %> but now i'm getting a error saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')" any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Just console.log(results) and you will have the answer. If there is no property then just do <%= Lcount %>